# Figure in standalone documentclass

Tags: floats, standalone

I am using the document class:`\documentclass{standalone}`. However, I am unable to use the commands `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`. What package do I need to include to be able to use the commands `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`.

Comment: why would you want a floating environment in standalone? That is a special class not for making documents. Almost any normal class will let you use floats, article, report, book, memoir, the koma classes, ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Essentially, I want to enclose a tikzpicture in the figure environment, with caption.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to put a _float_ into standalone, you just want to do the tikzpicture then re-include it into a float in your real document so it can float.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  The advantage with using `standalone documentclass` for a tikzpicture is it provides a pdf with no unnecessary white space, i.e., the pdf is completely filled with the picture generated by tikz, which makes it easier for me to include the image/picture in other files. If I were to use say `article` as a documentclass, then there are unnecessary white spaces, I need to contend with. (I can use tikz package under `standalone` documentclass to draw diagrams/pictures.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To reformulate the question: Can I add caption to a tikzpicture without using the figure environment, so that I can use it under the `standalone` documentclass?

Comment: @user17762 The standalone class is designed specifically for that purpose. You only need the figure environment in your document. See the manual for details.